# Emeditor右クリックメニューを非表示にしたい

Tags: emeditor

## 質問

添付画像のメニューを非表示にしたいです。
どの様にすればよいでしょうか？

## 環境

- EmEditor Professional(64Bit) Version 20.4.5
- Windows 10 64 Bit 20H2(Build 19042.746)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EmEditor の [カスタマイズ] ダイアログ ボックスの [ショートカット] ページの [エクスプローラのコンテキスト メニューにショートカットを追加] チェック ボックスをクリアしてください。
[image: EmEditor カスタマイズ - ショートカット]

Answer (score 0):

以下レジストリを削除で解決しました。

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\EmEditor
```